# React is batching two effects into one update?

Tags: reactjs

This is hard to explain so I included a codepen.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-yonath-8hr3pj?file=/src/App.js

Try toggling the button, and then commentating out line 16 and uncommenting line 15.

Why does the use of setTimeout allow the transition to work?

Comment: If `mounted` is initialized to `false`, then the `<div>` won't be rendered. When you click the button, `mounted` ends up becoming `true` at the same time `isOpen` gets set to true, so there's nothing to animate (opacity will already be 1 from the beginning of the `<div>` being rendered. By delaying setting `isOpen` to `true`, you give the `<div>` time to be rendered, so that `opacity` will change from 0 to 1 (triggering the animation) instead of becoming 1 instantlly.

Comment: Doesn't react re-render when state is mutated? So when useEffect[] runs, it calls setIsOpen(true) and then re-renders. Then since isOpen changed, useEffect[isOpen] runs, causing another re-render? 

About 1/25 times it works as intended so I don't think mounted and isOpen should normally mutate at the same time, it seems like there is some sort of batching occuring.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: After having submitted this behaviour to this open issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20863  Dan Abramov correctly pointed out that this behaviour is not related to React, or React `useEffect` hook specifically. I tried to update opacity imperatively in the *ref callback* and it shows the same behaviour:

```
ref={(node) => {
          console.log("OPACITY:", node?.style.opacity);
          // SYNCHRONOUS CHANGE - CSS transition does not work
          if (node) node.style.opacity = 1;
        }}
```

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

No, I don't think it's batching the effects, I think the reason of the glitch is that on the second rerender ( triggered by isOpen ), the DOM node, is for a moment undefined, hence DOM can't trigger the transition.
Check the sandbox I edited: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cohen-8rq544?file=/src/App.js

It's known that React paints to DOM asynchronously, you can see it in console, after the last render, you have `OPACITY: undefined` for a moment, before logging `OPACITY: 1`.
That's because it re-renders too fast and the node in the real DOM is not ready yet, but css transition needs it to perform the transition. The node is ready a few ms later.
Delaying a bit the second DOM paint with a timeout fixes that behaviour.

The libraries that animate components on mount like `react-spring` or `framer-motion` need to address this behaviour, you could check their codebase if you are interested to see how they address it in depth.

[image: LOG]

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, react is re-rendering before it can paint to the DOM so when it finally does paint, the opacity has already been set to 1?

Comment: I'm not sure, my guess is that the problem is that the node is undefined immediately on re-render. But I checked with the FADE button, and in that case the node is undefined as well, but the transition works, so I'm not sure, we should ask Dan Abramov :) . If you are trying to animate on mount I suggest you to use an animation library btw for more consistency.

Comment: I think it definitely has to do with a delay between renders, as the behavior gets more unreliable the shorter the delay. 1ms is 50/50 if the transition activates, where as 50ms is almost 100%. The second re-render happens in less than .1ms when I profile it as well. What I think is happening is that react is rendering so fast, by the time react-dom goes to paint the first re-render react has already diffed the second re-render. Setting a timeout gives react-dom a window to paint the first re-render. But this is just a guess.

Comment: That's how it looks, but if you toggle fast the FADE button in my example, it shows the same behaviour though the transition works well. I'm not sure if it might be relative to the fact the node on first render (mount) is not cached on virtual DOM.

Comment: Could be related to the fact that useEffect only runs after the render is [committed to the screen](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: Looks like a similar discussion was had [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20863)

Comment: @benten28 Not sure they are related, if you see I was partecipating at that issue discussion, in any case react@18 seems to have addressed the case with an heavy  blocking function triggered in useEffect . This case looks different though. In both cases setting the last *setState* at the bottom of the queue of the event loop worked. You say that the delay influences the behaviour, it doesn't look like it does, just by placing the *setState* at the bottom of the queue of the event loop with a `setTimeout(,0)` seems to fix it.  This was the same fix of the issue you mentioned.